# How can I enable cash on delivery payment method with WooCommerce subscriptions plugin

Tags: php, wordpress

How do I show the cash on delivery payment method on checkout page, with using variable subscriptions products.

I'm using WooCommerce Subscription plugin for taking recurring payments. It's taking recurring payments for the lifetime or till subscription expires. Currently, it looks like: But I don't want to take payment for the lifetime. I want to take payment as instalments.

Comment: Fix some lexical issues

Answer (score 1):

This WooCommerce Custom Payment Gateway plugin should do the trick - https://wordpress.org/plugins/woocommerce-other-payment-gateway/

Comment: just showing stripe pyament  method  on checkout page

Comment: Did you enable it in Woocommerce settings under the CHECKOUT tab. You should be able change the "Method Title" to COD or Cash on Delivery. Here is. a screen shot - https://ps.w.org/woocommerce-other-payment-gateway/assets/screenshot-2.png?rev=1716376

Comment: yes, i enabled but when i used woocommerce supscrtions plugin its not showing. just showing stripe payment method

Comment: I realized I said checkout - that is an old screenshot. It is now under the Payments tab. I just loaded it on my site (which also uses woo subscriptions) and it showed up. So if you go to Woocommerce > Settings > Payments > Custom Payments > and then change the title - you still see nothing? Do you have some custom CSS that might be hiding it?

Comment: Ah! I just figured it out - under subscriptions - you need to check "Accept Manual Renewals" then COD will show up. Your other subscription projects will still go through automatically - but anyone paying with COD will  have to be completed through Stripe or Woocommerce. Meaning you will have to change the status to "Complete" from the backend.